# Android get pic and name of contact using number

Tags: android, image, uri, contacts

I am using following code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
```

for retrieving contact info and. DISPLAY_NAME would help in getting name but how can I retrieve contact's pic also in possibly a URI format. I know how to do this using PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI but it is not present in PhoneLookup.

I need compatibility till sdk - 5.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try out below method to get the contact profile image:

**Get Contact Profile Picture**

```
private void GetContactPhoto() {

        Bitmap photo = null;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));

            if (inputStream != null) {
                photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            assert inputStream != null;
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**Get Contact Display Name**

```
private void GetContactName() {

        String contactName = null;

        // querying contact data store
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            // DISPLAY_NAME = The display name for the contact.
            // HAS_PHONE_NUMBER =   An indicator of whether this contact has at least one phone number.

            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }

        cursor.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact Name: " + contactName);

    }
```

**Get Contact Number**

```
private void GetContactNumber() {

        String contactNumber = null;

        // getting contacts ID
        Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

            contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        }

        cursorID.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);

        // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
        Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

                new String[]{contactID},
                null);

        if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
            contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }

        cursorPhone.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
    }
```

For more details check [HERE](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/android-get-contact-details-id-name-phone-photo/)

Comment: @GrlsHu I have a phone-number, I need to find name and picture on its basis not on basis of contact id or anything else.